# how to set default Class type parameter as null in Python?

Tags: python, parameters

I am new from the C# developer to learn python now and I am not very clear about the class type parameter in the Python function definition, especially the default null.

in C# I can set another class type as a parameter and make its default value as null in the current class function definition, and use its function if it is not null.  such thing like below

```
public class ClassA{
    public DoSthByA() {
      Console.WriteLine ("I am class A");
    }
    void DoSthWithB (ClassB b=null) {
      if (b != null) {
         b.DoSthByB ();
       }
    }
}
public class ClassB {
  public DoSthByB () {
    Console.WriteLine ("I am class B");
  }
}
```

but if I try to do this in python, like I define a function

```
def test(self,ClassB=None):
   ClassB.DoSthByB()
```

the system will warn that it is a none type which no DoSthByB attribute, I tried to search this but didn't find a good answer,  also I am not very clear about the python class type parameter which sometimes feels like duck typing more . just hope someone can help me on this, thank you very much ~

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround and works now, but not sure if this is a correct way in python

in the test function, I declare a classB type var class_b_ref first, then depends on the function parameter is None or not to pass the  real reference obj reference to class_b_ref

```
#version 1
def func_in_classA1(self,class_b_parameter=None):
    class_b_ref=ClassB
    if class_b_parameter== None:
        print "the parameter is null"
        return
    else:
        class_b_ref= class_b_parameter

    class_b_ref.DoSthByB()
```

PS: the version 1 works, but the system mentioned me " class_b_ref=ClassB" is unused since there is another value assign in "else". I think I still try to use the "casting" habits from C# but Python is a dynamic language, from the above code I changed to the version2

```
# Version2:
def func_in_classA2(self,class_b_parameter=None):
    if class_b_parameter== None:
        print "the parameter is null"
        return
    elif isinstance(class_b_parameter,ClassB):
        pass

    class_b_ref.DoSthByB()
```

it works, please kindly notify me if any better or formal way to do this in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this post, here is the correct way of doing this in python 3:

```
from typing import Optional
def test(self, b: Optional[ClassB] = None):
     if b is not None:
          b.DoSthByB()
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html